# "Navigating" a CSRF-protected website using HTTP requests and cookies keeps redirecting to the login page, only working in Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, http-post, restsharp

I am trying to get info from a website that has no public API. I can't give the website's name because you literally can only sign in with a work account created on their end, so there's no way for other people to test this without my credentials (which I am not giving out).

```
class Client
{
    public string PHPSESSID { get; set; }
    public Client()
    {
        this.Login();
    }

    public void Login()
    {
        string csrf;
        RestClient client;
        RestRequest csrfRequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        csrfRequest.AddHeader("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        csrfRequest.AddHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        csrfRequest.AddHeader("dnt", "1");
        csrfRequest.AddHeader("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
        csrfRequest.AddHeader("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36");
        csrfRequest.AddHeader("upgrade-insecure-csrfRequests", "1");

        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");
        request.AddHeader("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");
        request.AddHeader("referer", "{WEBSITE}/login");
        request.AddHeader("origin", "{WEBSITE}");
        request.AddHeader("host", "{WEBSITE}");
        request.AddHeader("dnt", "1");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddHeader("content-length", "118");
        request.AddHeader("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        request.AddHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");

        IRestResponse response;
        do
        {
            client = new RestClient("{WEBSITE}/login");
            response = client.Execute(csrfRequest);
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.PHPSESSID))
                this.setPHPID(response);
            csrf = this.FindCSRF(response.Content);

            client = new RestClient("{WEBSITE}/login_check");
            RestRequest bak = request.Clone();
            request.AddCookie("PHPSESSID", this.PHPSESSID);
            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "form%5Busername%5D={USERNAME}&form%5Bpassword%5D={PASSWORD}&_csrf_token=" + csrf, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            client.FollowRedirects = true;
            response = client.Execute(request);
            request = bak.Clone();
        } while (response.Content.Contains("error"));
    }

    public string FindCSRF(string input)
    {
        int find = input.IndexOf("value=", input.IndexOf("_token")) + 8;
        int find2 = input.IndexOf('"', find);
        --find;
        return input.Substring(find, find2-find);
    }

    public void setPHPID(IRestResponse response)
    {
        try
        {
            string cookie = response.Headers.ToList().Find(p => p.Name.Contains("Set-Cookie")).Value.ToString();
            if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie))
                this.PHPSESSID = response.Cookies[0].Value;
            else
            {
                int cookieStart = cookie.IndexOf("PHPSESSID=") + 10;
                this.PHPSESSID = cookie.Substring(cookieStart, cookie.IndexOf(';', cookieStart) - cookieStart);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            this.PHPSESSID = response.Cookies[0].Value;
        }
    }

    public void switchBranch(string branchID)
    {
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        request.AddHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        request.AddHeader("referer", "{WEBSITE}/message-board");
        request.AddHeader("dnt", "1");
        request.AddHeader("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
        request.AddHeader("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36");
        request.AddHeader("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1");

        RestRequest branchRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        branchRequest.AddHeader("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        branchRequest.AddHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        branchRequest.AddHeader("referer", "{WEBSITE}/message-board");
        branchRequest.AddHeader("dnt", "1");
        branchRequest.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        branchRequest.AddHeader("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36");
        branchRequest.AddHeader("x-branchRequested-with", "XMLHttpbranchRequest");
        branchRequest.AddHeader("origin", "{WEBSITE}");
        branchRequest.AddHeader("accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");

        IRestResponse response;
        RestClient client;
        string csrf;

        do
        {
            client = new RestClient("{WEBSITE}/");
            client.FollowRedirects = true;
            RestRequest acc = request.Clone();
            acc.AddCookie("PHPSESSID", this.PHPSESSID);
            response = client.Execute(acc);
            if (response.Content.Contains("login"))
            {
                this.Login();
                Console.WriteLine("Login Required");
                continue;
            }
            csrf = this.FindCSRF(response.Content);

            client = new RestClient("{WEBSITE}/branch-switch");
            acc = branchRequest.Clone();
            acc.AddCookie("PHPSESSID", this.PHPSESSID);
            acc.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "office_select%5Boffice%5D=" + branchID + "&office_select%5B_token%5D=" + csrf, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        } while (response.Content.Contains("error"));
    }
}

public static class RequestExt
{
    public static RestRequest Clone(this RestRequest req)
    {
        return req;
    }
}
```

A lot of this I just intercepted from the website using Postman then copied the auto-generated code over, so if there are certain headers that can help, I probably don't know about them.

I mostly fixed the login issues (though I literally have to fail before it gives me a working CSRF token, thus the while loops). The problem is that when I try to go to {WEBSITE} in Client.switchBranch, to start actually doing stuff, it **returns a JSON with a redirect to the login page.** It *doesn't* do this in Postman, I have been able to successfully interact with the website and gather information... once or twice (logging in even sometimes fails in the browser).

It seems entirely random to me, but there MUST be some kind of common factor here. I'm guessing it's something to do with the PHPSESSID cookie or the lack of a "keep-alive" connection header (which caused RestSharp to throw an error when I tried to implement it; even if that is the problem, I still don't know how to solve it). The login request and response headers in Chrome's developer tools, intercepting from the website, look something like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Ab9.png)

Comment: The answer to this is almost always, without exception, "I didn't exactly mimic something in a header / cookie".

Comment: @hoodaticus So how do I mimic "keep-alive" headers if RestSharp doesn't let me.